# Cufon (jQuery?) selector not to select children

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, cufon

I have a very basic and usual list menu with a submenu:

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>
        About
        <ul id="sub-menu">
            <li>Child1</li>
            <li>Child2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And then I have a Cufon selector applying a font to the menu:

```
Cufon.replace('ul li a');
```

Is there any way to select only the first level of the menu and disregard the other? Right now both levels get the font, but I would like to use something else for submenu.

I am very much a beginner with Javascript, Cufon and jQuery, I tried using child selectors but I had no luck with that. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your JavaScript library uses CSS-style selectors; you can just use

```
<ul class='containingMenu'>
 <li>Home</li>
 <li>
    About
    <ul id="sub-menu">
        <li>Child1</li>
        <li>Child2</li>
    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

with this selector

```
ul.containingMenu > li > a
```

where the `>` causes the selector to apply only to `a`'s that are direct children of `li`'s that are direct children of the `ul.containingMenu`.

↪ [See this example in action at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FVzeQ/).

Comment: For the `a`? I meant to read from the question that the asker wanted to match all direct children of the `<ul>`, and then all the `<a>` tags inside of them. I made a little clarification.

Comment: `ul.containingMenu > li` (also) matches the li containing _About_; if this li contains an `a` -- immediate child or a descendant -- it will be matched by `ul.containingMenu > li a`, something that OP does not want.

Comment: OK, you're right. I forgot that the `<ul>` was also contained in a `<li>`. Fixed :-)

Comment: Chose yours as a best answer.. Sorry, had forgotten about the question. :)